# How can I link my HSBC account to PayPal in Egypt?

Tags: debit-card, paypal, visa, egypt

I have a HSBC VISA Debit card in Egypt. But I don't know how to link it with PayPal and what I need to do for that. I read that debit cards are not acceptable, but I don't know if this is true or not.

Does anyone have experience about similar cases and could describe to me how to link my account with PayPal? Is it possible? What exactly should I do? Or do I need a credit card instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try logging into your account and trying to link your card ?

Comment: yes, before one month ago, but till now i didn't receive these charge amount from them so i can't verify my account.

Answer (score 1):

I did that successfully. First you add the card details on PayPal and they execute a transaction over it. The transaction wasn't visible immediately on HSBC Online but i called the bank and they gave me the code in the description field of the transaction.